Why does my recursive memoization function cause a 'Maximum Call Stack Exceeded' error in JavaScript?
While solving fabonocci problem using recursion and memoization in JavaScript, I got "Maximum Call Stack Exceeded" error when I try to run it with large inputs. To troubleshoot, I copied the solution from GeeksforGeeks (GFG) and that works correctly. However, I'm struggling to understand why my approach fails.
Here is my code
function topDown(n) {
  const modulus = 10 ** 9 + 7;
  const dp = {};
  function rec(value) {
    if (value <= 1) {
      return value;
    }
    if (dp[value] !== undefined) {
      return dp[value];
    }
    dp[value] = (rec(value - 1) + rec(value - 2)) % modulus;
    return dp[value];
  }
  return rec(n);
}


Here is working solution
function topDownTwo(n) {
  const modulus = 10 ** 9 + 7;
  const dp = {};
  function rec(value) {
    if (value <= 1) {
      return value;
    }
    if (dp[value] !== undefined) {
      return dp[value];
    }
    const ans = (rec(value - 1) + rec(value - 2)) % modulus;
    dp[value] = ans;
    return ans;
  }
  return rec(n);
}


Only difference is how value is returned from recursive function.
dp[value] = (rec(value - 1) + rec(value - 2)) % modulus;
return dp[value];

and
const ans = (rec(value - 1) + rec(value - 2)) % modulus;
dp[value] = ans;
return ans;

When I call these functions with a large value of n, like 9657, my version throws a stack overflow error, while the GFG version runs without any issues.
I'd appreciate any help in understanding the cause of this issue.

Well, you are creating a variable on the stack, which the original code does not.  Stack frames use memory, and you will have one for each level in the recursion.

@TimRoberts wouldn't that mean though that the 2nd code snippet would be the one we'd expect to fail, not the first

FYI, in my browser, both are failing.

I tried and found that both functions throw maximum call stack error, are you sure that the 2nd function worked?

I can repro in Chrome, using 7000 as input. In Firefox, passing 15000, it's complete random, sometimes both fail, or both pass or any pass... I'd suspect JIT inlining might be a reason why one can go a bit farther than the other, but that's just speculation. User jrmk will know better.

All JS engines eventually fail if you go high enough

@JaromandaX but the "interesting point" of this question, is what makes one version fail before the other?

@Kaiido - that would be covered by the first comment :p - bun fails at the same point for both which I find more interesting :p

@JaromandaX nope, read the second comment ;-) And your results with bun are quite surprising. In Safari (So JSCore too) I get the same behavior as in Chrome, but from 35000 instead of 7000.

@LãNgọcHải. I got this error while trying to solve this problem on geeksforgeeks.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/introduction-to-dp/1
I tried in Node.js version 21, it failed for the input I mentioned above
